# Does "curtain time" means "on show time"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

The Japanese-English dictionary, it says "curtain time" means the time that show starts.
But I seldom see this phrase on actual posters or tickets.

I am now writing a Japanese to English translation about an upcoming music concert. Is it correct to write 
"Doors open XX P.M.     Curtain Time XX P.M." or any other better choices?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In US English, we just say "Curtain at 8:00" to mean that the show starts at 8.

Comment: It is long-standing theater jargon -- the time when the "curtain goes up" at the start of a stage show.  But for an ad "show starts at 8:00 PM" is probably better, as "curtain time" would probably confuse a few people.

Comment: Curtain time refers to a theater venue, or old movie theater (pre 1990's) and less a concert, modern movie theater, etc.. For concerts it is often seen as " xx:x0 Show time", "Performance starts/begins at xx:x0".

Comment: Theaters used to have actual curtains--heavy fabric--that hung between the audience and the stage; the curtain was raised, the stage revealed, and the play began.  The curtain would be lowered between acts while scenery was being changed.  After the performance the curtain would be lowered, then raised while the audience applauded the actors in what was called a "curtain call."

Answer (score 8):

1)

> The Japanese-English dictionary, it says "curtain time" means the time
>   that show starts. But I seldom see this phrase on actual posters or
>   tickets.

Curtain time does indeed mean the time the show starts, it's a phrase seldom used, which is why you do not see it in popular advertisements.

[Curtain time](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/curtain_time)

> The beginning of a stage performance. ‘curtain time is at 8 p.m.’ - OLD.

It's more typically associated with theatre than music.

2)

> I am now writing a Japanese to English translation about an upcoming
>   music concert. Is it correct to write "Doors open XX P.M. Curtain Time
>   XX P.M." or any other better choices?

If your music concert is operatic, you could use *curtain time*, but if the music concert is popular music, this would sound too formal.

For a less formal alternative you could use:

> Doors open XX P.M. Concert starts XX P.M.

or

> Doors open XX P.M. Music starts XX P.M.

or, as @HotLicks mentioned below:

> Doors open XX P.M. Performance starts XX P.M.

Comment: Or "Performance starts ..."

Answer (score 2):

In theatrical circles, we speak of both 'curtain up' and 'curtain down' times.  The colloquial expression might be 'what time does the show go up?' or 'what time does it come down?'   'Curtain up at 8.00, curtain down at 10.00'.   But the curtain is rarely mentioned in advertising etc.  It would more likely be 'Monday at 8.00, doors open 7.30'.